# Comparing two vectors (predicted/expected)

Tags: r, logistic-regression, prediction, glm

I am trying to do something close to a **shallow** bootstrapping but I am struggling with data type. Here is the script :

```
library(languageR)
data(dative)
sub1<-dative[grepl("S10|S11",dative$Speaker),]
mod_sub1<-glm(RealizationOfRecipient~Verb+SemanticClass+LengthOfRecipient+AnimacyOfRec+DefinOfRec+PronomOfRec+LengthOfTheme+AnimacyOfTheme+DefinOfTheme+PronomOfTheme+AccessOfRec+AccessOfTheme,family='binomial',data=sub1)
comp_sub1<-dative[!grepl("S10|S11",dative$Speaker),]
expected_compsub1  <- comp_sub1$RealizationOfRecipient
predicted_compsub1 <- predict(mod_sub1,ndata=comp_sub1,type="response")
predictions_sub1   <- prediction(predicted_compsub1,expected_compsub1)
performance_sub1   <- performance(predictions_sub1,"tpr","fpr")
plot(performance_sub1)
```

In the **Global Environment** window :

```
- expected_compsub1 : Factor w/ 2 levels "NP","PP" : 1 1 1 ...
- predicted_compsub1 : Named num [1:1076] 0.1561 0.9889 ...
```

I tried to use `ifelse (predicted_compsub1 >0.5,"NP","PP")` but it doesn't work either.

I obtain the following **error** :

```
predictions_sub1   <- prediction(y_predicted_compsub1,expected_compsub1)
Error in prediction(y_predicted_compsub1, expected_compsub1) : 
Number of predictions in each run must be equal to the number of labels for each run.
```

I can see that it is a matter of type but I fail to see how to fix the problem.
Thanks for your insight !

Comment: Where is the prediction() function coming from? It is not loaded with that package.

Comment: The usual `predict` functions, like `predict.glm` take a `type` argument. You specify `type = "response"` to get the predicted y values rather than, say, the linear predictor. Look at the documentation for you `prediction` function - whatever package it comes from - to see if it has something similar.

Comment: prediction() comes from the ROCR library. In the documentation, it works like this : prediction(predictions, labels, label.ordering = NULL) ... I can't see how it relates to "type" (which I use in predict() ).

Comment: @Parselmouthintraining : Then why is there no library call for ROCR???

Comment: @42 : It was written higher in the script and I forgot to copy it...

Answer (score 1):

I finally found what was wrong. I wasn't using if else at the right place :

```
library(languageR)
library(ROCR)
data(dative)    
sub1<-dative[grepl("S10|S11",dative$Speaker),]
complementaire_sub1<-dative[!grepl("S10|S11",dative$Speaker),]
mod_sub1<-glm(RealizationOfRecipient~LengthOfRecipient+AnimacyOfRec+DefinOfRec+PronomOfRec+LengthOfTheme+AnimacyOfTheme+DefinOfTheme+PronomOfTheme+AccessOfRec+AccessOfTheme,family='binomial',data=complementaire_sub1) # minus subjects,verbs
expected_compsub1  <- sub1$RealizationOfRecipient
predicted_compsub1 <- predict(mod_sub1,newdata=sub1,type="response")
predicted_compsub1 <- ifelse(predicted_compsub1 > 0.5,0,1)
predictions_sub1   <- prediction(predicted_compsub1,expected_compsub1)
performance_sub1   <- performance(predictions_sub1,"tpr","fpr")
sum(predicted_compsub1 & as.numeric(expected_compsub1))/sum(as.numeric(expected_compsub1))
sum(predicted_compsub1 & as.numeric(expected_compsub1))/sum(predicted_compsub1)
plot(performance_sub1,main="S10|S11")
```

Now it works ! Thanks everyone for your help !