# glm output in R expected 0 and 1

Tags: r, glm

I'm starting to learn R and I'm playing around with the Titanic dataset on Kaggle. When attempting logistical regression on the survival rate, my expectation was for 0 and 1?

```
PassengerId Survived    Pclass  Sex Age SibSp   Parch   Fare    Embarked    Title   FamSize FamSizeD    AgeRange
1   0   3   male    22  1   0   7.25    S   Mr  2   small   21-30
2   1   1   female  38  1   0   71.2833 C   Mrs 2   small   31-40
3   1   3   female  26  0   0   7.925   S   Miss    1   single  21-30
4   1   1   female  35  1   0   53.1    S   Mrs 2   small   31-40
5   0   3   male    35  0   0   8.05    S   Mr  1   single  31-40
6   0   3   male    28  0   0   8.4583  Q   Mr  1   single  21-30
7   0   1   male    54  0   0   51.8625 S   Mr  1   single  51-60
8   0   3   male    2   3   1   21.075  S   Master  5   large   0-20
9   1   3   female  27  0   2   11.1333 S   Mrs 3   small   21-30
10  1   2   female  14  1   0   30.0708 C   Mrs 2   small   0-20
```

---

```
logistix <- glm(Survived ~ Pclass + Sex + Embarked + Title + FamSizeD + AgeRange,
                data = train,
                family = 'binomial')

Prediction <- predict(logistix, test, type = "response")

Prediction
```

[image: train]

Comment: You need to define a threshold for the probability, such as `0.5`, to determine if the prediction is considered to be `1` or `0`.

Comment: For example, `P_class <- ifelse(prediction > 0.5, 1, 0)`. After that, based on the `P_class` vector to determine if the event occurs.

Comment: This isn't really a question about R, it's about how to interpret a logistic regression. I've flagged it to be moved to stats.SE.

Comment: I thought the question was answered by @ycw at least to the degree of sophistication shown by the questioner.

Comment: There are also many results for an SO search on `[r] glm binomial prediction`. This one has the suggestion by ycw: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709106/comparing-two-vectors-predicted-expected